# ListView not visible

Tags: android, listview

I get elements from MySQL database and input them into a ListView. The arraylist in the ListView gets the elements but the ListView does not display on the screen. Here is the code:

```
String name, url;
final List<String> myContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ListView listView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_inbox);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myMessages);
    url = Values.baseUrl + "getData.php?sender=" + Values.sender;
    System.out.println(url);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            try {
                JSONArray details = response.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject detail = details.getJSONObject(i);
                    myContacts.add(detail.getString("receiver"));
                    System.out.println(myContacts.get(i));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.append(error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myContacts);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    try {
        String output = myContacts.get(pos).toString().trim();
        System.out.println(output);
        Values.receiver = output;
        Intent intent = new Intent(AllMessages.this, CreateMessage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void goToAdd(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(AllMessages.this, AddContact.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is layout file - activity_main_inbox :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewText"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="Inbox"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myMessages"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></ListView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:onClick="goToAdd"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The log displays:

```
V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2942f886 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4e99420 {com.example.farhaan.test/com.example.farhaan.test.MainActivity}} show : false
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the ListView's height and width to something else than `wrap_content`? Try `match_parent` and ignore android studio's warnings (it may tell you that `wrap_content` might be better).

Comment: Oh and you should use `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter once you've added the data

Comment: Yeah I thought so after adding the second comment. Try the `notify...` thing

Comment: match_parent does not work.
Also sometimes the list does get displayed. It is totally random. Those times the log shows the following 3 lines: 

    D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb92b9138 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb93460f8

    I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2ff361f6 time:35910615

    V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{2adcb561 token=android.os.BinderProxy@22b87723 {com.example.farhaan.test/com.example.farhaan.test.MainActivity}} show : false

Comment: Sorry, I cant display them in 3 different lines

Comment: I'm sorry can't help you there... I just thought it might be a) because the layout is incorrect or b) because the listview does not refresh once the data is set.

Comment: I know about notifyDataSetChanged. It is required if the dataset is changed after adding the arrayadapter to the listview. But here I'm adding string to the list before adding the arrayadapter to the ListView. I think I should not be requiring notifyDataSetChanged!

Comment: You are calling the `jsonObjectRequest` before setting the `adapter` to the `listview`. **BUT**, I think you're forgetting that requests in Android are Asynchronous. So it is possible that you made the request, but even if it's not finished, you are already setting the still empty `adapter` to the `listview`. I suggest putting these lines `ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myContacts);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);` inside your `onResponse()`. Try it out. Cheers!

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you.